# jQuery select groups of tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I had this structure:

```
<p>Some text random 1</p>
<p>Some text random 2</p>
<p>Some text random 3</p>
<div><img src=""></div>
<p>Some text random 4</p>
<p>Some text random 5</p>
```

I want to surround groups of p tags in a div element, does anyone know of the best way to go about this. The preferred output would be:

```
<div class="p-tags">
    <p>Some text random 1</p>
    <p>Some text random 2</p>
    <p>Some text random 3</p>
</div>
<div><img src=""></div>
<div class="p-tags">
    <p>Some text random 4</p>
    <p>Some text random 5</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why you can't give the expected structure before ?

Comment: best option is to generate the preferred structure while generating the DOM itself, if thats dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `wrapAll`

```
$("p").slice(0,3).wrapAll('<div class="p-tags"></div>');
$("p").slice(3,5).wrapAll('<div class="p-tags"></div>');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bpLwta1z/)**

Answer (score 2):

To Wrap all the elements in one, you can use `wrapAll` 

To Find element above image and below image, you can use `prevAll`and `nextAll` respectively.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('img').parents('div').prevAll().wrapAll('<div class="p-tags"></div>');
$('img').parents('div').nextAll().wrapAll('<div class="p-tags"></div>');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/coolshivster/t988v0ys/1/)